# When does $-\frac{\pi z}{2}\cot(\pi z)+\frac{1}{2}=0$ where $z$ is a complex variable?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Let $z$ be a complex variable. Is there someone who can show me when does :$$-\frac{\pi z}{2}\cot(\pi z)+\frac{1}{2}=0$$

Note: I have tried using trigonometric formulas but it didn't work. Maybe I should write $\cot(z\pi)$ as a series sum, but it will be complicated to set $z$ as a complex variable.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Substitute and let $u=\pi z$ therefore we have: $$-\frac{1}{2}(1-u \cot u)=0$$

Therefor, $u \cot u=1$ therefore $\cot u=\frac{1}{u}$ therefore $\tan u=u$ or $\tan {\pi z}=\pi z$.

Comment: I think we cited that z is complex variable

Comment: I seek for conditions about z the complex variable or to set it closed form if it was exist

Comment: Indeed you did. I'll edit the first line.

Comment: There is no closed form.

Comment: There are 7 real solutions.

Comment: why there is no closed form ,have you reason for this ?

Comment: Simpler form. <

Comment: i give you example what i think is may for 0 <|z|<1 the equation can be satisfied

Comment: Some solutions are. Not all satisfy $0<|z|<1$